Check iPhone vs iPad device type on background thread
I have this code:
public enum DeviceUtil {
  public static var isPhone: Bool {
    return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
  }
}

And I got warning saying UIDevice API has to be on the main actor. I have a few places where I have to check the device type in background thread.
Is there other API i can use that works on background thread?

Why not check it once at launch and simply store the property somewhere.  The device type won't change

Are you in an async context? If so, you can just await to get the value. Alternatively, you can get the value just before the background thread starts, and send it to the background thread. UIInterfaceIdiom is Sendable. How are you starting the background thread?

@Paulw11 iiuc i would get a warning about shared static var and race condition

@Sweeper No i am not in async context. I can send in either the idiom or just a boolean flag, but it's quite inconvenient to pass the value.

If you're not in an async context, how did you get in a "background thread"?

if it's not main actor, is it background thread (or background actor?)

Swift 6
struct Platform {
    nonisolated(unsafe) static private var _isPhone: Bool?
    nonisolated(unsafe) static var isPhone: Bool {
        if let _isPhone { return _isPhone }
        let isPhone = MainActor.nonisolatedUnsafe { UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone }
        _isPhone = isPhone
        return isPhone
    }
}

private extension MainActor {
    static func nonisolatedUnsafe<T: Sendable>(_ block: @MainActor () -> T) -> T {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            MainActor.assumeIsolated { block() }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync { // !!!: sync here
                block()
            }
        }
    }
}



is using GCD considered a bad practice in the Swift concurrency world? I am actually migrating from GCD to Swift concurrency

There is no need to call UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom every time.  The device won't change.
You could replace the computed property with a static assignment
public enum DeviceUtil {
  public static var isPhone = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
}

Then, as long as your first access to this property is on the main thread you are good.

While it is correct that "as long as your first access to this property is on the main thread you are good", this code gives a warning that will be an error in Swift 6. "Main actor-isolated default value in a nonisolated context".

A static var is lazy. What's the point of the function wrapper?

@Sweeper I don't run betas, so I guess I will learn to deal with that when Swift 6 is released.

I'm still surprised that there is no other API that i can use to tell the device. But I think i am going with this approach, except that I will mark this static var as nonisolated(unsafe), and manually make sure that it's only set once when the app is launched.

The warning you're seeing is because UIDevice API calls should be performed on the main thread due to UIKit's thread-safety requirements. To address this, you can create a utility function that ensures the check is performed on the main thread, even when called from a background thread.
import UIKit

public enum DeviceUtil {
    @MainActor
    public static var isPhone: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
    }
    
    @MainActor public static func isPhone(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            completion(isPhone)
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(isPhone)
            }
        }
    }
}

Usage
checking device type in Background Thread
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    DeviceUtil.isPhone { isPhone in
        if isPhone {
            print("Running on an iPhone")
        } else {
            print("Running on an iPad")
        }
    }
}

checking device type in main thread
DeviceUtil.isPhone { isPhone in
    if isPhone {
        print("Running on an iPhone")
    } else {
        print("Running on an iPad")
    }
}

Alternate way
import UIKit

public enum DeviceUtil {
    public static var isPhone: Bool {
        return MainActor.run {
            return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
        }
    }
}

extension MainActor {
    static func run<T>(closure: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            return try closure()
        } else {
            return try DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                return try closure()
            }
        }
    }
}

Usage
let isPhone = DeviceUtil.isPhone
print(isPhone ? "Running on an iPhone" : "Running on an iPad")


Is there a DispatchQueue.sync equivalent in Swift concurrency so that I can access this flag synchronously without using GCD?

i don't think so but you can do it to put that code in extension. please check above.
